# Is there a way to share a queue from multiple Google Music accounts

Tags: google-play-music

I'd like for everyone in our lab to be able to queue up music from their own Google Music libraries to a shared broadcasting playlist. Thoughts on whether this is possible and, if so, where to start?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without them all sharing one Google account